# Linnworks and Consumer is not authorized

Tags: magento-2.1, api

[Linnworks](https://www.linnworks.com/support/settings/channel-integration/channels/magento-2/magento-2-configure-channel-settings) report the issue with error message:

> Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Here is response from there request:https://www.example.com/rest/V1/stockItems/lowStock?scopeId=0&qty=100000000&pageSize=2000&currentPage=1

```
<response>
<message>Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</message>
<parameters>
<resources>Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory</resources>
</parameters>
</response>
```

We have not developed API but only created Admin-User required for linnworks and they are coming with these issues and here are few of them:

- https://www.example.com/rest/V1/stockItems/lowStock?scopeId=0&qty=100000000&pageSize=2000&currentPage=1 
  it is returned with an error message stating 'object moved'.
- All permission seems to be granted and can you please check if `Is Token authorize` is  set to true?
- List item

I have checked these threads already: [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37884687/949003) , [akamai](https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2016/02/19/magento-2-rest-api-invocation-examples-and-why-they-matter), [Git Issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5110), [mag2](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1570) and magento docs.

PS:
I am not developing api/script and its all-about Linnworks and magento version: 2.1.3.

Please guide if someone face same issue with Linnworks or other platforms and what could be cause of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was because of Rewrite condition of `HTACCESS` file.

Adding the below rewrite condition sorted out the issue:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rest/V1/stockItems/lowStock/.*$